# Magento trying to display product price range based on "size attribute" on Product display and category pages?

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.8, product, magento-1.9.1

I have **Configurable** products that their **prices** are based on their **Simple** attributes **Size**.  As is Magento's displays product price of **$0.00** on category and products pages.

example:

- (Configurable) Product: Picture Frame (model-ABC) note: price is set to $0.00
- (Simple) Size: 4"x6" $10.00 (model-ABC-46)
- (Simple) Size: 5"x7" $20.00 (model-ABC-57)
- (Simple) Size: 8"x10" $30.00 (model-ABC-810)

How can I display the product price range of $10.00 - $30.00 on the **Category** and also individual **Products** pages? What is the possible solution for this change? Where is it implemented?

ps. Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Super product attributes configuration` option. If you are crating the product in admin panel you see it under `Associated Products` tab.

After associating your simple products to your configurable product you can set the price difference according to their sizes; e.g. in the attached image size *M* will be *10* units more expensive than default price:

[image]

Alternatively you can change the difference calculator method to *percentage* instead of *fixed*.

Plus, your *Size* attribtue (super attribute) must have a `Global` scope and be applicable to `All Product Types` (you can verify this under `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes`: Search for `Size`).

Comment: Thank you Hatef for the reply. The configurable product price are set to $0.00, since all products prices are based on attribute size! Super product attributes are fixed prices.

Comment: @user2774042 i'm not sure if I exactly understand what your problem is. But let me explain my answer a little more.. among the associated products if you set the price of cheapest one (let's say size XS and S in my photo above) to the configurable product; and leave the *Price* field empty (*just like price fields for XS, S in my photo*); it will automatically assign that price to those simple products (*size XS and S*) - and if you want a different price for a different size you just need to add their difference in the price field (*M in my photo*). So if XS and S are 10$ then M will be 20$.

Comment: I don't want to have associated prices.  The product prices are based on their attribute size.  ie. A picture frame style A, with three different sizes. As explained on top.